# Getting "illegal State exception:can't be transactional and expect a COD message" in jUnit

Tags: junit

I am running a JUnit test case to test a message flow. In between , I am getting "illegal State exception:can't be transactional and expect a COD message" as exception in JUnit. Is this related to the error in message flow or it is related to the java framework written for JUnit ?. But In spite of this error, I could see the blank message getting transmitted to the nodes constructed in message flow. If an error occurs in Junit , won,t the message flow also throw an exception? Please help

Comment: please post the code that you have tried.

Comment: For eg:
public final getDefaultProperties()
{
properties.addProp("RecordlastFlag","false");
return properties;
}